# Outdoor LED lights runnng dim/flickering

Tags: led, outdoor

These lights are Kichler hardscape step lights and mounted and installed professionally through a stone wall.  They are wired to a 300 watt multitap transformer and the other two lines work fine.  The first in the series won't light up (even when a new working fixture is installed), the other five run dim and flicker.  Tried replacing the first light.  No go, wired it directly to the feed and it worked great and bright.  Wired it into the second light station and it ran dim and flickered.  Kichler customer support had no advice.  Any takers?

Comment: Seems pretty clear that the supply wire is damaged.  Can you do any electrical tests on the wire - voltage, resistance?  Can you inspect the wire at all or is it all hidden?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a poor connection, that is also crossing over into "arc fault".

It should be readily apparent; when you touch it, it'll be warm or hot.